# Comparing NSDate and UIDatePicker ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Trying to form an if statement which compares the current date on the left to the date chosen in UIDatePicker on the right, I think this is the right code I was given by a fellow Stack Overflow user, they shouldn't be able to perform this action, and they can't but I need to create a pop-up telling them why not:

```
  //Get the current date
  NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

  //Unable to set notification for same day
  //[datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];

  self.datePicker.date  = [NSDate date];
  if ([pickerDate compare:datePicker] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something wasn't right." message:@"That did not work and your alarm was not set." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

I am receiving the following error from implementing this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDatePicker timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b9373a0'

Answer (score 1):

Double check your call to the `compare:` method. You are comparing against the date picker instead of the date picker's date.

You want:

```
if ([pickerDate compare:datePicker.date] == NSOrderedAscending) {
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, got this as a new error: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDatePicker copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ba86c80'

Comment: That's a whole new issue. Close this question and ask another one for the new issue if needed. Be sure you point out the actual code causing the new problem. But first do some debugging. If needed, see http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1